# QGIS extend raster layers extension

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to extend a raster layer to another layer's extension (my input raster layer is smaller). The new raster cells should have 0 value.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be doable with gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html by giving the extended size with the -projwin parameter together with -a_nodata 0 for defining the nodata value.